# PRAW SEARCH ImportWarning: sys.meta_path is empt

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to learn Python and at the same time learn PRAW.  I'm trying to run the below from PyCharm and keeping the error that is below.  The code below is the basic first tutorial.

```
import time

import praw

r = praw.Reddit('PRAW related-question monitor by u/_Daimon_ v 1.0.'
            'Url: https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/'
            'pages/writing_a_bot.html')
r.login()
already_done = []

prawWords = ['praw', 'reddit_api', 'mellort']
while True:
subreddit = r.get_subreddit('learnpython')
for submission in subreddit.get_hot(limit=10):
    op_text = submission.selftext.lower()
    has_praw = any(string in op_text for string in prawWords)
    # Test if it contains a PRAW-related question
    if submission.id not in already_done and has_praw:
        msg = '[PRAW related thread](%s)' % submission.short_link
        r.send_message('_Daimon_', 'PRAW Thread', msg)
        already_done.append(submission.id)
time.sleep(1800)
```

Error

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Reddit
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Reddit", line 6, in <module>
r.login('rbevans', 'bowstead')
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 1266, in login
self.user = self.get_redditor(user)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 890, in get_redditor
return objects.Redditor(self, user_name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 663, in __init__
fetch, info_url)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 72, in __init__
self.has_fetched = self._populate(json_dict, fetch)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 127, in _populate
json_dict = self._get_json_dict() if fetch else {}
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\objects.py", line 120, in _get_json_dict
as_objects=False)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\decorators.py", line 161, in wrapped
return_value = function(reddit_session, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\praw\__init__.py", line 526, in request_json
data = json.loads(response, object_hook=hook)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 318, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 343, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=632, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.29.138.114', 50568), raddr=('198.41.208.139', 80)>
sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=608, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketType.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('172.29.138.114', 50566), raddr=('198.41.208.142', 443)>
C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py:2150: ImportWarning: sys.meta_path is empty
```

Process finished with exit code 1